# pandasをpdと略す意味とは？

Tags: python, pandas

pandas以外も同様ですが、短く省略することにどのような意味があるんでしょう？
何行もコードを書いているうちに正式名称を毎回入力するのが面倒になったとかそういう理由なんでしょうか？

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が見つかります。[Python : as はモジュールにエイリアスを付けることができる記号](https://commte.net/7349), [【Python】import・as・from文の使い方](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/import-as-from-py/), [【Python】importの使い方はコレです！（from,as）](https://pg-chain.com/python-from-import), [【Python】asの使う場面と使い方について](https://yumarublog.com/python/as/) 概ね疑問のとおりではないでしょうか？ 出自・原典を知りたいというなら調査を続ける必要があるでしょうね。

Answer (score 6):

`import <モジュール名> as <別名>` の形式で記述することで、任意の名前でモジュールをインポートできますが、(想像の通り) 主に長い名前を省略する目的で使用されることが多いかと思います。

"Pandas" の省略形がなぜ "pd" なのかは、"Panel Data" が名前の由来だからだそうです。

[Pandas - Wikipedia (EN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_(software))

> The name is derived from the term "**pan**el **da**ta"

Comment: pandas という名称は小文字で始まるようです (質問者さんは小文字始まりで書いてるのでここにコメント)。https://pandas.pydata.org/ では小文字で始まるけど正確な理由は見つけきれてない。ちなみに wikipediaではシステム都合上 最初が大文字になってしまったはず(なので 記述内容は小文字始まりで URLでは大文字)