# 連立方程式をPythonで解こうにも動かない

Tags: python, numpy

連立方程式を解いて下記を入力し走らせてみましたがうんともすんとも言いません。
何がまずいんでしょうか？

```
from numpy.linalg import solve
left = [[2, 1],
        [1, 3]]

right = [1, 13]

print(solve(left,right))
```

追記
＞このサイト Online Python Compiler (Interpreter) - Programiz
確かにご提示のサイトではうまくいきました。
環境の情報というのは何を答えればよいのでしょうか？

anacondaで呼び出したJupiterを用いて上記のソースコードを試した結果が質問のものです。

Comment: このサイト [Online Python Compiler (Interpreter) - Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/) で質問のソースコードをそのまま実行させたら何かしらの結果が表示されています。「うんともすんとも言いません。」というのは何かの誤解か、環境構築とか使い方を間違えていたりするのでは？

Comment: paiza.ioのPython3でも結果（[-2.  5.]）が表示されましたのでコードに問題はないようです。「何がまずいんでしょうか？」とのことですが、環境等の情報を質問に追記してください。現状では”何も問題ない”としか言えません。計算結果は出力されているが、質問者さんが見つけられていない（非表示にしている）だけなどが考えれます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Comment: 一度立ち上げなおしてもう一度行ったら表示されました。
しかし
import numpy as np
と
numpyをnpと定義したにも関わらず
from numpy.linalg import solve
ではなく
from np.linalg import solve
と入れた際は
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'np'
などと表示されました。これは何がまずいんでしょうか？

Comment: モジュールのエイリアス名は他の import 文では使用できません。

Comment: そうなんですね。知りませんでした。ではas npと定めることにどんな意味があるんでしょう？

Comment: @モルフォ さん、質問自身はpandasについてですが、同様の疑問を扱っている記事がこちらでしょう。[pandasをpdと略す意味とは？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/92573/26370)

Answer (score 1):

パッケージを最新にしてみると動くかも知れません

```bash
$ conda activate base

$ conda update conda
$ conda update --all

$ conda list numpy
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.21.5           py39h6c91a56_3
numpy-base                1.21.5           py39ha15fc14_3
numpydoc                  1.5.0            py39h06a4308_0
$ conda list jupyter
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39h06a4308_8
jupyter_client            7.4.8            py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_console           6.4.4            py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_core              4.11.2           py39h06a4308_0
jupyter_server            1.23.4           py39h06a4308_0
jupyterlab                3.5.0            py39h06a4308_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

ただし
conda-forge リポジトリーなど, Anaconda公式ではないパッケージ利用しているとトラブルになることがあります。つい最近も conda-forgeで ipywidgets 系が動作しない(表示されない・動作がおかしい) などがありました(一週間ほど)

- base 環境は何もいじらず保持しておいたほうがよい
  パッケージ追加, conda-forge リポジトリー有効化 … など行うなら, 別に新しい環境を作成しそちらで
- トラブルが発生した場合, base環境で動作確認してみると動くかもしれない

---

また, (軽く動かして見るような) JupyterLab での動作確認には [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) を使う方法もあります。Webブラウザー内で Python ＆ NumPy (あるいはその他) が動作するもの